# SwiftUI: Calendar view instead of DatePicker on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, calendar

I'm wondering whether SwiftUI have calendar view for macOS.
DatePicker requires user to pick date instead of always display the whole calendar.
Some awesome libraries like `FSCalendar` and `ElegantCalendar` are for iOS and iPadOS.
I'm not planing to use Mac Catalyst since my application only target macOS.

Comment: What does the doc say about it?

Comment: It's up to your macOS version, again, according to the doc.

Comment: I don't want DatePicker. I want Calendar View. I did not see any doc about SwiftUI calendar

Comment: Search for DatePicker in the doc.

Comment: Found it. Thank you so much for helping